# Understanding Apache error log

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, logging

I was checking my Apache error log this afternoon, for my localhost server - Windows Vista Home Edition is my OS.
The server has `mod_aspdotnet` installed as an extension.

This is my error log:

```
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:36 2011] [notice] mod_aspdotnet: CorBindToRuntimeEx has loaded version v2.0.50727 of the .NET CLR engine.
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:39 2011] [notice] ModSecurity for Apache 2.1.3 configured
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:41 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.6 (Win32) PHP/5.2.5 mod_ssl/2.2.6 OpenSSL/0.9.8g mod_aspdotnet/2.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:41 2011] [notice] Server built: Sep 20 2007 14:13:35
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:41 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4512
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:42 2011] [notice] mod_aspdotnet: CorBindToRuntimeEx has loaded version v2.0.50727 of the .NET CLR engine.
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:45 2011] [notice] ModSecurity for Apache 2.1.3 configured
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:48 2011] [notice] Child 4512: Child process is running 
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:48 2011] [notice] Child 4512: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:48 2011] [notice] Child 4512: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:48 2011] [notice] Child 4512: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Fri Apr 01 10:54:48 2011] [notice] Child 4512: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

What does: `[notice] mod_aspdotnet: CorBindToRuntimeEx has loaded
    version v2.0.50727 of the .NET CLR engine.` mean - is it an error?

Although I can understand Apache error logs at a basic level, this log is a new one - I renamed my old log to error.log.bak and re-started the server.

Please can anyone help me with this?

I did look up on Google for `mod_aspdotnet` errors, but there wasn't much on it, so that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3):

It's telling you that `mod_aspdotnet` has loaded v2 of the .NET framework.  It's not an error
 - unless you were expecting it to load in a different version of .NET, of course!

Comment: Thanks Steve! :) Maybe I need to learn how to customise the error.log!

Comment: The `[notice]` text indicates that is just an informative message. If it was `[error]` or `[warning]` it would indicate something  more serious. You set what level of messages is logged by using the `LogLevel` option the Apache configuration files, though notice is a special case. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel.